# How to treat ~/.local/share/flatpak/appstream/flathub/ for backups?

Tags: backup

I'm creating a backup of my Ubuntu 20.04 every evening in order to be able to do desaster recovery. My approach is to include all files and directories and exclude paths based on knowledge of their purpose rather than include specific directories because I fear not having included data written by applications whose absense prevents restoration.

Updates to `~/.local/share/flatpak/appstream/flathub/` are annoying during backups because the backup fails due to missing files. I would like to find the app removing and modifying files from that directory in order to disable it before the backup **or** exclude the directory from the backup if it contains no program or user data for flatpak applications.

I assume `~/.local/share/flatpak/appstream/flathub/` is similar to `/var/cache/apt/archives` or `/var/lib/apt/lists/` which I both don't include in my backup as they're easy to restore with more up-to-date data with a simple `apt-get update`. I don't find any clear evidence for that however.

Of course, I prefer to exclude the files if they have no purpose in the backup. Which approach makes more sense?

Comment: You determine the purpose of a backup. So please add your intensions. For me, a backup concerns my user files. I do not care of system settings or user configuration files, so for me, these would be out. Actually, I use "include" for hidden folders rather than "exclude".

Comment: @vanadium Including instead of excluding is too risky for a backup in my opinion. I added an assumption to the question. Maybe it's more easy to verify or falsify it. My intention is to check whether `~/.local/share/flatpak/appstream/flathub/` is definitely forever completely useless in a scenario where I want to have the state of my laptop of yesterday evening after a disk failure or similar catastrophe - compare to `/var/cache/apt/archives` as suggested.

Comment: You should clearly state the purpose of the backup at the start of your question, not in a comment.